# How to call function on web3

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js, truffle

I'm trying to call a function on web3, but it doesn't get executed on web3.
It just doesn't popup Metamask wallet to ask for the transaction approval, so it doesn't execute.

Solidity function:

```
function Deposit(uint _amount) payable public{
    require(msg.value == _amount);
    funds[msg.sender] += _amount;
}
```

Function on web3

```
  deposit = async(depositAmount)=>{
    const web3 = window.web3
    const ethers = web3.utils.toWei(this.depositAmount.value, 'ether')
    await web3.contract.methods.Deposit(depositAmount).send({from: this.account, value: ethers})
  }
```

How is the function called

```
<form className="deposit" onSubmitCapture={(event) => {
              event.preventDefault()
              const amount = this.amount
              this.deposit(amount)
            }}>
              <input type="text" className="inputs" placeholder="Amount to deposit" 
              ref={(input)=>this.amount = input}/>
              <input type="submit" className="btn" value="DEPOSIT"/>
        </form>
```

I'm loading web3 and loading blockchain data correctly, and deposit function is called in a button component. Just wanted to know if it has something to do with this code, or the problem might be somewhere else. The smart contract is correctly migrated with truffle and ganache.

Comment: I'm not familiar with web3, but shouldn't you use `await deposit(depositAmount.value)`?

Comment: @IłyaBursov It throws an error if I put await in front of it

Comment: @brt88 did you initialize web3? did you pass a provider or if you use metamask did you connect the wallet?

Comment: @JacopoMosconi Yes, I did all that

Comment: it prints any error? @brt88

Comment: @JacopoMosconi no

Comment: @brt88 then i'm pretty sure the error is away, if you initialized everything, the code you posted seems ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize web3 properly. According to the docs, you should initialize as `const web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider).`

Answer (score 0):

You can use with **gasLimit** param.

```
await web3.contract.methods.Deposit(depositAmount).send({from: this.account, value:
   ethers, gasLimit: "21000"})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { useWeb3React } from "@web3-react/core";
import { CONTRACT_ADDRESS } from "../../Utils/constants";
import { contractAbi } from "../../Contracts/arrue-contract-abi";



 const signer = library.getSigner(account).connectUnchecked();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        contractAbi,
        signer
      );
      const isActivatedBorrowersValue = await contract.activatedBorrowers();
```